# Export Webpage to PDF (using PHP)

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

I have a web form on my web site that I need to export to a PDF file. What is the best web to approach and do this?

My website is written in PHP. And I would like the exported PDF file to look exactly the same as how it looks on my website.

The CSS that I used are not anything over-the-top.

The form is about 2 pages in length if you convert it to a physical paper form.

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaMerrell: I am open to all suggestions and not just PHP or back-end solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Fpdf will help you to do what you asked..

http://www.fpdf.org/